# NextJS - Failed to compile. Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote. jsx-quotes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eslint

I'm trying to compile my nextjs app (NextJs 13) and keep getting this error. Here is my eslintrc.js file (I've added "..." to make it shorter in some places):

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 0,
    'eslintreact/no-danger': 0,
    'react/jsx-max-props-per-line': 0,
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': 0,
    'no-console': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control': 0,
    'no-nested-ternary': 0,
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'no-alert': 0,
    'react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values': 0,
    'import/extensions': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'linebreak-style': 0,
    'react/state-in-constructor': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions': 'off',
    'react/function-component-definition': [
      2,
      {
        namedComponents: 'arrow-function',
        unnamedComponents: 'arrow-function',
      },
    ],
    'max-len': [
      2,
      1050,
    ],
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': [
      'error',
      {
        max: 1,
        maxEOF: 1,
      },
    ],
    'no-underscore-dangle': [
      'error',
      {
        allow: [
          ...
        ],
      },
    ],
    'object-curly-newline': 0,
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 0,
    'react/jsx-one-expression-per-line': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/alt-text': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-autofocus': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 0,
    'react/no-array-index-key': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': [
      'error',
      {
        components: [
          ...
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

and my eslintrc.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

I've tried adding  the following changes:
at the end of eslintrc.js:

```
...
    ],
    'jsx-quotes': ['error', 'prefer-double']
  },
};
```

eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "jsx-quotes": ["error", "prefer-double"]
  }
}
```

I still get the same errors though. I'm using Visual Studio Code if that matters.

Edit:

Screenshot of terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error means you have the following pattern in your code:

```
<Component props='value' />
```

instead of:

```
<Component props="value" />
```

You can either turn it off using the following config:

```
"jsx-quotes": "off"
```

or change all your usage to double quotes.

Comment: I added that to both eslint files and still get the same error

Comment: @Mitch Can you provide a reproducible Github repo and/or screenshot of the errors in terminal?

Comment: https://github.com/Mischa-bc/nextjs_template.git

Comment: also added the screenshot to my answer